# How to see if the size of a file is multiple of 4 bytes

Tags: bash, sh, modulo

I'm writing a bash script for a university exercise, which reads the byte size of the files passed to it as arguments and adds them up. The size is added if it is a multiple of 4 bytes. If not, I have to make it a multiple of 4. In particular, the text of the exercise says like this: "If the size D of the file is not a multiple of 4 bytes, fill in the last D
mod 4 bytes with zeros. "

Now, to check if the size of a file is a multiple of 4 bytes I do this, but i don't know if this is right:

```
D=`stat -c '%s' file.txt`  #command sostitution
if (( ($D/4)*4 == $D ))
then 
    echo it's ok
else
    echo it isn't ok
fi
```

Also I would like to know, given the size D of the file (in bytes), how to fill in the last D
mod 4 bytes with zeros, if D is not a multiple of 4 bytes.

The problem is that I don't understand what it means to "fill in the last D
mod 4 bytes with zeros ".

Comment: is the file possibly generated by `objcopy` or similar?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
d=$(stat -c '%s' file.txt)
if ((d % 4 != 0)); then
   truncate -s "$(( (d + 3) / 4 * 4 ))" file.txt
fi
```

Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 3):

Instead of stopping at the modulo, directly compute the `null` padding amount to use with `truncate`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Pad files with null to the alignment
# align ALIGNMENT FILE...
# $1: The alignemnt in bytes
# $@: The filenames to get aligned
####
# Example usage:
# align 4 file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt

# Take alignment as first argument
alignment=$1

# Shift first argument out
shift

# Iterate all remaining arguments as filename
for filename; do
  # If filename is a real file and has write permission
  if [ -f "$filename" ] && [ -w "$filename" ]; then
    # Get file size in bytes
    size=$(stat -c '%s' "$filename")

    # Compute how much padding would be need for alignment
    padding=$((alignment - size % alignment))

    # If file need padding
    if [ $padding -gt 0 ]; then
      # Pad file with padding nulls
      truncate -s +$padding "$filename"
    fi
  fi
done
```