# Check if a file's hex dump has modulo 4 length

Tags: bash, sh

I am trying to write a script that, taking a file as argument, checks if the hex dump of the file has a mod 4 length. If the length is not mod 4 it must add 00 to the end of the dump to make it mod 4

I tried with hexdump

```
D=$(hexdump filename)
if [ $((${#D}%4)) != 0 ]
then
    D+=00
fi
```

and with od

```
D=$(od -t x filename)
if [ $((${#D}%4)) != 0 ]
then
    D+=00
fi
```

but both methods not working

I think the problems are as follows:

I include the offset columns in variable D when I only have to consider the hexdump.
For example:

```
cat file.txt
// Hello World!
//This is a file .txt

od -t x file.txt 
//0000000 6c6c6548 6f77206f 21646c72 6968540a
//0000020 73692073 66206120 20656c69 7478742e
//0000040 0000000a
//0000041
```

The columns 0000000 0000020 0000040 0000041 must not be inside D.
In practice, inside D there must be 6c6c65486f77206f21646c726968540a736920736620612020656c697478742e0000000a

Also, I have to modify that dump so that it has a mod 4 lenght and I don't know if it is enough to simply add 00 at the end.

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see if the size of a file is multiple of 4 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67322171/how-to-see-if-the-size-of-a-file-is-multiple-of-4-bytes)

Answer (score 1):

```
D=$(xxd -p $1|tr -d '\n')
while [ $(bc<<<$(echo -n $D|wc -c)%4) != 0 ];do D+=00;done
```

does not include columns

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to examine the hex dump? Just pad the raw file with zeros if necessary.

```sh
padump () {
    local size=$(stat -f '%z' "$1")
    local i
    ( cat "$1"
      for ((i=size; i%2>0; i++)); do
          printf '\0'
      done ) |
    hexdump
}
```

Usage: `padump filename`

The argument to `stat` is unfortunately not portable; on Linux, try `stat -c '%s' "$1"` (the code above was written on macOS).

The modulo of the above is 2 because four hex digits corresponds to two bytes of file.

Anyway, I'll note that in your attempt, `od` already adds more padding than you bargained for, and outputs the bytes in the wrong order. The final value at offset 0x0041 is the single byte 0x0a and the zeros before it actually belong *after* it, and are padding. The other hex values are similarly swapped; 0x6c is the character `l`, but occurs first in the dump - read as a regular hex dump, 6c6c6548 spells `lleH`.  You can fix this with options;

```sh
#!/bin/sh

od -t 2x --endian=big "$1" |
sed 's/^[^ ]* //;s/ //g;$d'
```

Because `od` already adds the padding, this is probably the simplest solution. The above also discards the offsets (the first column; `sed 's/^[^ ]* //'`) and removes any remaining spaces between the hex digits (`s/ //g`), and the final line with just an offset (`$d`).  However, the `--endian=big` option is Linux only.  Alternatively, use `-t 1x` and add padding as above.